# How to convert JSON response to an Array

Tags: android, json, kotlin

```
"nodates":"[\"13-05-2021\",\"14-05-2021\"]"
```

Hello, I need to convert this JSON string into an Array. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use a JSON parser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Parse Like this :

```
String jsonArray = "{\"nodates\":[\"13-05-2021\",\"14-05-2021\"]}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray);
        JSONArray jsArr = jsonObject.getJSONArray("nodates");
        Log.e(TAG, "array : " + jsArr);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```